# Error in creating procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql

What may be the possibilities of getting an error in the following query?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `tbl_assessment_notes`(
  `var_reason` VARCHAR,
  'var_attr2' VARCHAR,
  'var_note' VARCHAR
) 
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS
    (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      tbl_assessment_notes
    WHERE
      reason = var_reason  AND attr2 = var_attr2
  ) THEN
UPDATE
  tbl_assessment_notes
SET
  note = CONCAT(note, var_note),
  TIMESTAMP = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
WHERE
  attr1 = var_attr1 AND reason = var_reason ELSE
INSERT
INTO
  tbl_assessment_notes(
    pk_assess_note_id,
    attr2,
    attr3,
    reason,
    note,
    TIMESTAMP
  )
VALUES(
  NULL,
  var_attr2,
  NULL,
  'confirmation',
  var_note,
  'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
) ;
END IF ;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
  'var_reason' VARCHAR,
  'var_attr2' VARCHAR,
  `var_note` VARCHAR,
  'var' at line 2
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is to update a row if it exists or else creates a new row and insert values into it.

Comment: What is the error message? (append it to the question)

Comment: where is that code containing `'var_attr1' VARCHAR,
  'var_attr2' VARCHAR,
  var_title` VARCHAR,` you code doesn't have such piece in it.

Comment: @ManojShukla Sry I just misjudged the error. Now it's edited.

Comment: No problem.. @YashParekh.

Answer (score 0):

Please use updated query

```
DELIMITER $$ 
 CREATE PROCEDURE `tbl_assessment_notes`
(var_reason  VARCHAR(255), 
var_attr2 VARCHAR(255),
var_note VARCHAR(255))  
BEGIN   
IF EXISTS
    (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      tbl_assessment_notes
    WHERE
      reason = var_reason  AND attr2 = var_attr2   ) THEN UPDATE   tbl_assessment_notes SET   note = CONCAT(note, var_note),   TIMESTAMP
= 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' WHERE   attr1 = var_attr1 AND reason = var_reason ELSE INSERT INTO   tbl_assessment_notes(
    pk_assess_note_id,
    attr2,
    attr3,
    reason,
    note,
    TIMESTAMP) VALUES(NULL,var_attr2,NULL,'confirmation', var_note,   'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' ) ; 
END IF ;
 END $$
 DELIMITER ;
```